# accessing xampp using computer name

Tags: xampp, computer-name

i've installed xammp on my new notebook and i can access it using `localhost` or `127.0.0.1` but NOT when using the computer name.
using the computer name also worked previously on my desktop pc. 
i've already tried to disable the firewall which didn't help - any ideas?
thanks

Comment: What error message do you get? I receive a `403` status code when I try it with the hostname. That is because of what @Dan said.

Comment: it's trying to connect forever and ends with timeout ..

Answer (score 3):

First thing to check is what your computer name is resolving to.

Go to the command prompt and compare the output of the following two commands.

```
ping computername

ping localhost
```

What you'll probably find is that localhost resolves to 127.0.0.1 (Or ::1 if you're using IPv6, too) and computername will resolve to your network cards IP address.

If so, ensure that XAMPP is listening on all IP addresses, or  add in your computers IP if it's going to remain static.

You COULD potentially add a hosts entry which resolves computername to 127.0.0.1 but I wouldn't really recommend that route personally.

Comment: i've tried that - it's exactly as you described it.
i will try modifying the xampp config file ..

Answer (score 3):

In addition to Dan's answer, which explains why it's not working, here's a fix.

The error message I get looks like this. It's in German, but never mind. It says there's a new security concept. You're only allowed to access from the local network. It also says how to change it.

> Zugriff verweigert!
>
> Neues XAMPP Sicherheitskonzept:
>
> Der Zugriff auf das angeforderte Objekt ist nur aus dem lokalen
>   Netzwerk möglich.
>
> Diese Einstellung kann in der Datei "httpd-xampp.conf" angepasst
>   werden.
>
> Sofern Sie dies für eine Fehlfunktion des Servers halten, informieren
>   Sie bitte den Webmaster hierüber. Error 403

In your xampp folder there's a file called `httpd-xampp.conf` In my case it is here:

> C:\xampp\apache\conf\extra\httpd-xampp.conf

In this file at the very bottom find where it says

```
<LocationMatch "^/(?i:(?:xampp|security|licenses|phpmyadmin|webalizer|server-status|server-info))">
    Order deny,allow
    Deny from all
    Allow from 127.0.0.0/8 
    ErrorDocument 403 /error/HTTP_XAMPP_FORBIDDEN.html.var
</LocationMatch>
```

and comment out the `Deny from all and Allow` rows:

```
<LocationMatch "^/(?i:(?:xampp|security|licenses|phpmyadmin|webalizer|server-status|server-info))">
    Order deny,allow
#    Deny from all
#    Allow from 127.0.0.0/8 
    ErrorDocument 403 /error/HTTP_XAMPP_FORBIDDEN.html.var
</LocationMatch>
```

Now restart the apache and it should work.

**Edit:**

You can also add your hostname as an Allow directive:

```
Allow from 127.0.0.0/8
Allow from pc001.MYCOMPANY.local
```

Find out your complete hostname including the domain from a command line:

```
C:\>hostname
pc001

C:\>ping pc001
Ping pc001.MYCOMPANY.local [...]
```

This probably is the way to go! It is better than opening the doors to everyone.

Additional info can be found in the [Apache doc](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/howto/auth.html).

---

A word of warning: It is now possible to access your xampp installation (webserver, database and so on) from every machine in your network. **This is a security risk**.

Comment: Good addition. Just a quick question - why not add the IP address into the Allow From, thereby allowing local browsing only? (Genuine question, I'm not familiar with XAMPP)

Comment: Becaue if his address is from a DHCP server than that might not work permanently. In a trusted environment I'd just turn the check off I guess.

Comment: That's fine, just wanted to check my understanding

Comment: @Dan: I added the hostname to the answer.

Comment: @simbabque: i'm also using the german version - it's not the "neues sicherheitskonzept" but a timeout :)

Comment: That could still be the same, couldn't it? It took quite a long time for me. Better check it anyway.